# How to edit and modify a class with ILSpy + Reflexil

Tags: windows, dll, patching, c#, assembly

In the Maxsea.SmartDesktop.dll, I want to edit and modify class b1g.

There is this in :

if (isCrackedResult != null && isCrackedResult.IsCracked)

and I want to modify for this :

if (isCrackedResult == null && !isCrackedResult.IsCracked)

I've try to save b1g.cs, edit with Notepad++ and modify but i don't arrive to inject the new one ...

Someone can help me  ?

Thanks

Comment: Typically you shouldn't face this problem... Are you missing anything? Reflexil should let you manipulate the code instantly.

Comment: ... I don't know ...
If you want to see or to test you can DL this 
https://expirebox.com/download/acc551e93e79ef558482e4f2e03204d5.html
It's a screenshot to ILSpy and the .dll

Comment: you should not save the .cs file but rather the whole assmelby

Comment: I can also propose you this. Download Visual Studio Community 2017 and dotpeek. Dotpeek can directly import any .net exe in a new visual studio project, and it does it pretty good. Plus, you can have ano of the best coding suites for anything else..

Comment: It's too complicated for me ... I do not have much knowledge in the field ...

Comment: @ChrisTsiakoulas:
I only download ILSpy_Master_2.4.0.1963_Binaries and reflexil.for.ILSpy.2.1.AIO

Comment: Its not that hard... trust me!

Comment: @ChrisTsiakoulas: he asks me to download things to which I do not understand anything ...

Comment: If you try to modify the DLL, you can ? Maybe I forget another library but which one ....

Comment: I just suggested a different tool combo. If you dont feel comfortable with those tools, just see if you are missing some minor detail

Comment: @ChrisTsiakoulas:
I've try your solution and ... i understand nothing ...sorry i'm neebie

Comment: What do you mean when you say you tried it?

Comment: I installed the 2 software, then I opened my .dll file
The tree is completely different, I have not found the class to modify ... It is too complex for me this combo ...
You can DL the archive hosted on expirebox? maybe you'll see what I might miss ... thanks

https://expirebox.com/download/63ee31ff9652ba5d895d12cdf600da0e.html

Answer (score 5):

Try using [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy). It includes an ability to inject the recompiled code, and has the same interface as ILSpy. Use "Edit Method" option on the method you're editing, then "Build" and save the assembly. You won't need Reflexil then.

Comment: I downloaded it and i tried to modify the file ... but it doesn't work ... :'(
I've a lot of errors ... I don't understand why ...

Comment: I just use dnSpy for windows 2012 is there alteranate solution for working with windows server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about straight code editing - sometimes it can't be recompiled correctly due to either obfuscation or bad references, etc. You have to edit the IL instead (lookup the Common Intermediate Language and learn about it). I would suggest, instead of doing != null and !cracked, just do if(false).